# how is once loading(src=...) js files in .load()?

Tags: javascript, load, jquery, jquery-load

this html code is the html that i want to call with .load().i want load once js file in page header.I do not want again load js file to html code.
following code is true worked. but other events jQuery in html code not worked.
what do i do?
js:

```
$('#icon a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = '#' + this.id;
        var title = $(id).attr('title');
        $(".title").toggleClass("suject").html(title);
        var url = $(id).attr('href')+' .insert';
        $('.table_show, #num_count, #select_box, #input_search').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('.results').load(url).hide().show("slow")
        });
    });
```

html:

```
<div class="insert">
    <form action="http://localhost/Siran-mehdi/admin/hotel/insert" method="post">

<div class="myGrid">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>اطلاعات کلی</legend>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="mediumCell"> <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="نام پکیج تور خارجی" title="نام پکیج"></div>
        <div class="mediumCell"><input type="text" name="term" placeholder="مدت" title="مدت"></div>

<div class="auto_box">
    <b class="search_hotel">
    <span></span>    
    <div class="mediumCell"><input type="text" name="search_hotel" style="float: right;" alt="<?= base_url();?>admin/" id="tour" class="auto_complete" placeholder="هتل" title="هتل" /></div>
    <ul class="list_autobox_hotel"></ul>
    </b>
</div>
<div class="auto_box">
    <b class="guide_search">
    <span></span>
    <div class="mediumCell"><input type="text" name="guide_search" style="float: right;" alt="<?= base_url();?>admin/" id="tour" class="auto_complete" placeholder="راهنما" title="ارلاین"></div>
    <ul class="list_autobox_guide"></ul>
    </b>
</div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="wide"><input type="button" value="ثبت" class="submit"></div>
</div>
    </form>
</div>
```

With respect

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Add a JS file on the fly or an HTML file? Is the HTML shown above the html that you want to call or the one doing the calling?

Comment: you question is not very clear what is the problem you are facing  and/or what exactly you want to do and facing problems in achieving it...

Comment: i want load once js file in page header. yes, this html is the html that i want to call with .load().I do not want again load js file to html code. please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I think for this you need to use the getScript method, it loads a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.:

```
 $.getScript('ajax/test.js', function(data, textStatus){
   console.log(data); //data returned
   console.log(textStatus); //success
   console.log('Load was performed.');
});
```

Comment: page (html code) that there is #icon, have js file in head. when that .load() this html code must load js file again in it (i not want again load js file to page that load with .load()), how is onse load js file in head and use it in .load()

Comment: I am very sorry but going to have to ask you to rewrite your statement as I can not understand it

Answer (score 0):

the question was not clear to me but may be this will help

```
$('#icon a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = '#' + this.id;
        var title = $(id).attr('title');
        $(".title").toggleClass("suject").html(title);
        var url = $(id).attr('href')+' .insert';
        $('.table_show, #num_count, #select_box, #input_search').fadeOut('slow',function()
         {
        var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);
        var oScript= document.createElement("script");
        oScript.type = "text/javascript";
        oScript.src="yourJavaScriptFile.js";
        oHead.appendChild( oScript);
            $('.results').hide(); // if the element is empty no need to do hide()
            $('.results').load(url,function(){
              $(this).show();
           });
        });
    });
```

Comment: page (html code) that there is #icon, have js file in head. when that .load() this html code must load js file again in it (i not want again load js file to page that load with .load()), how is onse load js file in head and use it in .load()